# Exoplayer custom DataSource: Is there a way to make player ask for big chunks of data?

Tags: java, android, video, datasource, exoplayer

I have implemented custom `DataSource` to use with `ProgressiveMediaSource`.

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource() {
    MyDataSource.Factory factory = new MyDataSource.Factory(getItem());
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(Uri.EMPTY);
}
```

When I try to open several MKV files, the player calls `read(byte[] buf, int offset, int readLength)` function multiple times, passing `1` as `readLength`.

This results into **minutes** of initialization time before video starts playing (player wants to read 600000 times by 1 byte on the video I have)

For a test I've setup my own http server and formed an uri for this video, which I then used like this:

```
new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("sdfsdfds")).createMediaSource(uri); // uri looks like http://127.0.0.1:34567/video.mkv
```

and then player began to request `16384` as `readLength`. Video initialization takes few seconds.

Is there a way for me to tell player to read bigger chunks?
Or maybe there is a way to tell MatroskaExtractor to ignore some unwanted things? I still need seeking though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that for each read() I had to call some functions from native library, resulting in converting java structures to c++ and then back to java to get response.

This is very heavy operation for just 1 byte. Quick tests showed that preloading big chunks of data on java side speeds up initialization from minutes to seconds.

Comment: i am facing the same issue. did you get any solution to the issue ?

Comment: @deeppandya there is no possibility to read big chunks from MKV file, because of the format. But I did some experiments and found out that the bottleneck was in my own code, so I did some optimizations and greatly reduced time to load video

Comment: would it be possible for you to share the code for ref ?

Comment: @deeppandya I already described how I did my optimization in my own answer. I will not provide any code, but I will try to explain my problem and solution here. I had MKV video being loaded by C++ library. When ExoPlayer tries to open this video it starts to read one byte at a time for 200000+ times. Each this read() resulted in my own code creating Java objects, which are then passed into native library via JNI, after that native library loaded that one byte and returned it to Java code. Preloading big chunks of video on Java side into my own buffer solved the issue